# Library plugin manager in rust, is it even doable right now?

Tags: rust, async-await, ffi

I was wandering if my idea was even implementable: a **dynamic library plugin manager** with full support for async rust.

The implementation is divided into three main parts ([github repo](https://github.com/FrancescoLuzzi/plugin-system-example/tree/master)):

1. `my-interface`, an `async_trait` (with "normal" traits the approach seems to work fine, don't know to what extent)

   ```
   use async_trait::async_trait;
   #[async_trait]
   pub trait SayHelloService {
       async fn say_hello(&self);
   }
   ```
2. `my-master`, loads the `.dll`/`.so` and calls a creation function from the library that, given a `tokio::runtime::Handle`, returns a `Box<dyn SayHelloService>`

   ```
   use my_interface::SayHelloService;
   use tokio::{self, runtime::Handle};

   #[tokio::main]
   async fn main() {
       let lib = libloading::Library::new("target/debug/libmy_plugin.so").expect("load library");
       let new_service: libloading::Symbol<fn(Handle) -> Box<dyn SayHelloService>> =
           unsafe { lib.get(b"new_service") }.expect("load symbol");
       let service1 = new_service(Handle::current());
       let service2 = new_service(Handle::current());
       let _ = tokio::join!(service1.say_hello(), service2.say_hello());
   }
   ```
3. `my-plugin`, implements `SayHelloService` and this is the code that is blocking me

   ```
   use async_trait::async_trait;
   use my_interface::SayHelloService;
   use tokio::{self, runtime::Handle};

   #[no_mangle]
   pub fn new_service(handle: Handle) -> Box<dyn SayHelloService> {
       Box::new(PluginSayHello::new(handle))
   }

   pub struct PluginSayHello {
       id: String,
       handle: Handle,
   }

   impl PluginSayHello {
       fn new(handle: Handle) -> PluginSayHello {
           let id = format!("{:08x}", rand::random::<u32>());
           println!("[{}] Created instance!", id);
           PluginSayHello { id, handle }
       }
   }

   #[async_trait]
   impl SayHelloService for PluginSayHello {
       // this errors with "future cannot be sent between threads safely"
       async fn say_hello(&self) {
           // this should enable you to call tokio::sleep but EnterGuard is not Send :(
           // https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.enter
           let _guard = self.handle.enter();
           println!("[{}] Hello from plugin!", self.id);
           let _ = tokio::spawn(async move {
               let _ = tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
               println!("sleep 1");
           })
           .await;
       }
   }
   ```

Not being able to call `self.handle.enter()` creates all sorts of strange behavior for example:
(if you want more info I'll attach the crash log)

```
#[async_trait]
impl SayHelloService for PluginSayHello {
    async fn say_hello(&self) {
        let id = self.id.clone();
        let _ = self
            .handle
            .spawn_blocking(move || {
                println!("[{}] Hello from plugin!", id);
                // internal code of reqwest just crashes
                let body = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
                    .await?
                    .text()
                    .await?;
                println!("body = {:?}", body);
            })
            .await;
    }
}
```

I've also implemented a working implementation of `PluginSayHello`, but it doesn't feel like a full win to me.

```
#[async_trait]
impl SayHelloService for PluginSayHello {
    async fn say_hello(&self) {
        let id = self.id.clone();
        let _ = self
            .handle
            .spawn(async move {
                println!("[{}] Hello from plugin!", id);
                // calling tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                // errors with "there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime"
                let _ = sleep(Duration::new(1, 0));
                println!("slept 1");
                println!("[{}] Hello again from plugin!", id);
            })
            .await;
    }
}
```

To wrap things up:

- Is this approach even doable in rust?
- What errors do you find in my logic? (I'm pretty sure there are a bunch)
- Can you point me to a solution or a completely different approach?

Comment: You shouldn't use async with `spawn_blocking()`, the code won't run. If you want async you can use `spawn()`. And you don't need `enter()`.

Comment: If you can do it in C, you can do it in Rust, provided you're not afraid of the `unsafe` keyword. And with Rust's extremely powerful proc-macros you can probably get the syntax you want too.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman uhhh you right, during my experiments I messed with the "working" implementation, I'm going to update it, thanks

Answer (score 5):

This a deceptively non-trivial scenario.

First lets step back and explain why things are the way they are. Asynchronous primitives for I/O and timers work best when they are managed together since there needs to be some thread handling OS events. The Tokio `Runtime` offers this of course, but to avoid passing around a handle manually to register timers and I/O calls with the runtime, there is a thread-local ["current"](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.current) variable that stores a handle for the runtime that is executing the current task. So when you do something Tokio-specific like `tokio::time::sleep` it will use that thread-local variable to access the runtime's time manager. If there is no "current", you get the "there is no reactor running" error.

This becomes a problem in your plugin system because `tokio` will be linked statically in each of your compiled binaries (the master and the plugin) meaning they will have *different* thread-locals: i.e. what is "current" in the plugin is not the same as what is "current" for the master, even when using the same thread. Thus it appears you have tried to pass the handle manually and used `.enter()` but this solution isn't quite right.

One problem you encountered is this causes your async function to be `!Send` which can be resolved if you didn't need them to be `Send` by using `#[async_trait(?Send)]`, but I assume you do. Another problem if the tasks can move between threads, `handle.enter()` only sets the current runtime *of the current thread* and your task may at some point be moved to a different thread.

What you need is for your `async` task to have the "current" runtime *only while it is executing*. You can do this with a `Future` wrapper:

```
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;

use tokio::runtime::Handle;
use pin_project_lite::pin_project;

pin_project! {
    struct WithRuntime<F> {
        runtime: Handle,
        #[pin]
        fut: F,
    }
}

impl<F> WithRuntime<F> {
    fn new(runtime: Handle, fut: F) -> Self {
        Self { runtime, fut }
    }
}

impl<F> Future for WithRuntime<F>
where
    F: Future
{
    type Output = F::Output;
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, ctx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let this = self.project();
        let _guard = this.runtime.enter();
        this.fut.poll(ctx)
    }
}
```

Which you could then use like `WithRuntime::new(handle, async { ... }).await` (full code [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=18984c77ef2ab7c709820609c86e6f98)). The exact way to integrate it with your current trait may be awkward but I think it needs to change anyways.

Another issue with your current setup is you assume one runtime will always be calling your service. That may not be true; there are configurations like in Actix-Web where there are multiple single-threaded runtimes running. I think your code would still work, but it could be suboptimal. So you should probably pass the "current" handle on each async method invocation. You could probably make a macro that can handle this transparently for plugin writers.

Lastly, you should be warned that Rust's ABI is not stable. What you have is not guaranteed to work between compiler versions (or even with the same compiler?). It will *likely*, *mostly* work, but still not a guarantee. Normally you would design a proper FFI (foreign function interface) layer to communicate through, but the Rust's types required (`Poll`, `Context`, `Box<dyn Future>`) are not FFI-safe so you would need a FFI-safe shim (like from [stabby](https://docs.rs/stabby/latest/stabby/#async) which you should totally check out) for it to really work (though still not sure what you'd do for `Handle`).

And there's probably other stuff I've missed since I'm not sure why `handle.spawn(async { ... })` doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for this thorough explanation, I'm going to take a new stab a it with `WithRuntime`, that flew way past my head.

Comment: I've tried passing the `current handle` to the async function, but 1 run over 10/15 a panic is logged: `thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime', /$HOME/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/tokio-1.33.0/src/time/interval.rs:138:26` even though the execution finishes. Regarding the original question `WithRuntime` is indeed the answer